# JSON Object broken using json_encode when apostrophies are present

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, prepared-statement

Here's the situation:

My program accepts input entered by users into a form and saves it in a MYSQL database using PHP's PDO with Prepared Statements.

The data is retrieved via an AJAX call and encoded to JSON using json_encode, like so:

```
echo "<script> var jsonData = '". json_encode($profileData) . "';</script>";
```

Then parsed using JQuery:

```
var Profile = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
```

This works fine, **until a user enters a `'` char.**

i.e. If a user enters the word

> I'm

It would be escaped and stored in the DB like this: `I\'m`

Once retrieved from the DB, a JSON encoded string would look like this:

```
<script> var jsonData = '{"fname":"Daniel","about":"i\\'m a nerd"}';</script>
```

Although the `'` is escaped, it seems to break the JSON.

I have seen people posting find/replace style work-arounds, but I would prefer to avoid this approach.

Surely there is some method that handles this, or am I initializing the JSON Object incorrectly somehow?

Any help much appreciated, any more info required just ask :)

Comment: The syntax highlighting here shows it, you've over-escaped that `'`.

Comment: When using PDO prepared statements, you should not manually escape `'` in the database, PDO will handle storing/retrieving it correctly for you. `I'm` should be stored as `I'm`, not as `I\'m`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have not done any manual escaping. The prepared statement is storing `'` in the DB as `\'`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ..But you are right, that extra backslash has gotta go :)

Comment: Damn you magic quotes! XD Using shared host had to get them to turn it off..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve the problem would be to omit the quotes in JS:

```
echo "<script> var jsonData = " . json_encode($profileData) . ";</script>";
```

which will result in

```
<script> var jsonData = {"fname":"Daniel","about":"i\\'m a nerd"};</script>
```

Then `jsonData` will already be an object and doesn't have to be parsed. Though the escaping might be a bit off then.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! (I knew it would be something simple) But as @JoachimIsaksson points out in comments, it looks like I am also doing something funny which is causing the double backslash.

Answer (score 0):

> Once retrieved from the DB, a JSON encoded string would look like this:
>
> ```
> <script> var jsonData = '{"fname":"Daniel","about":"i\\'m a nerd"}';</script>
> ```
>
> Although the ' is escaped, it seems to break the JSON.

Note that JSON is here concerned about escaping the backslash. Thus, the quote is not escaped - you still have to do it so as not to mess up the quotes you put around it.

```
echo "<script> var jsonData = '". json_encode($profileData).replace(/'/g, "\\'" . "';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON_HEX_APOS parameter when you are encoding the JSON

```
json_encode($profileData, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

This will turn the single quote into a special escape value that only JSON understands